# __CSVRead() function jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a csv file, which has only one column and multiple row. I want all thread go through all of line in file and each thread read one line, from beginning to an end, stop thread when an end of a file. How can I do that with CSVRead() function in Jmeter.

> Example: my file name is: Perf_EC.csv and have 10 rows

Comment: Do you know how many lines in your csv file?  And do you want each thread read only one line or each thread should read all lines?

Comment: I don't know, but i change to using csv data set config, it can handle my issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to your Test Plan
2. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the "Loop Count"

   ```
   ${__groovy(new File('Perf_EC.csv').readLines().size(),)}
   ```
3. That's it, the number of Loops in the Loop Controller will be adjusted dynamically according to `Perf_EC.csv` file size

   [image]

---

- PS1: the recommended way of reading data from files is using CSV Data Set Config where behaviour what to do when file ends and [sharing mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) are configurable using GUI
- PS2: if you cannot use the CSV Data Set Config for some reason and you file contains only one column - you can go for [__StringFromFile function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) instead